# How to spam a key in Lua

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I want to use it on my logitech mouse.

I know it's a bad code because I don't know Lua.

```lua
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if input.IsKeyDown(KEY_L) then
        PressKey("l")
        Sleep(0)
        ReleaseKey("l")
        PressKey("enter")
        Sleep(0)
        ReleaseKey("enter")
    end
end
```

Comment: `input.IsKeyDown` is not a standard LGS/GHUB function.  Where did you find it?  Are you using some additional scripts?

Comment: Do you want to spam while the left mouse button is down?

Comment: Replace `if input.IsKeyDown(KEY_L) then` with `while input.IsKeyDown(KEY_L) do`

Comment: now I have this, `Syntax Error: Line: 8`
 `function OnEvent(event, arg)
         while input.IsKeyDown(KEY_L) do
            PressKey("l")
            Sleep(0)
            ReleaseKey("l")
            PressKey("enter")
            Sleep(0)
            ReleaseKey("enter")
         end
`

btw, I dont know where did I get `input.IsKeyDown`, and no i want to press 1 key, to start spam a word

Comment: `1` key on the keyboard?

Comment: `Do you want to spam while the left mouse button is down?` or can i use it, when i press `mouse4`?

Comment: Add one more `end` at the end.  This should fix syntax error.

Comment: yep i did it, so now, can i put it to `mouse4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spamming while mouse button 4 is pressed

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4 then 
     repeat
        PressKey("l")
        Sleep(10)
        ReleaseKey("l")
        PressKey("enter")
        Sleep(10)
        ReleaseKey("enter")
     until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4) 
  end
end
```

Comment: if I hold down mouse4, it stops writing further

Comment: uh sorry, my bad, i disabled my buttons

Comment: but, can i put here more, than 1 word?

Comment: Yes, `PressAndReleaseKey("h","e","l","l","o","enter","w","o","r","l","d","enter")  Sleep(10)`